# Getting the minutes from a date time by subtracting

Tags: sql, sql-server

HI I Have 2 datetimes fields. One is appt_scheduled and the other is appt_confirmed.

I would like to know if the times are within 5 minutes. This would be an indication that the appointment was a 'walk-in' then the formula can display 'walkin' on the row.​ I guess we can say that the date part has to be the same.

typical values are:

```
2016-12-21 08:40:00.000 - 2016-12-20 15:42:19.890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a `case`.  Something like:

```
select (case when appt_confirmed < dateadd(minute, 5, appt_scheduled)
             then 'walk-in'
             else 'scheduled'
        end) as AppointmentType
. . .
```

This assumes the confirmation is always after the schedule (although that condition could also be checked).

Comment: Use  `when ABS(datediff(minute, appt_confirmed, appt_scheduled)) < 5`

Comment: @LaughingVergil . . . Don't use `datediff()` if you really want 5 minutes.  It counts the number of minute boundaries between two values, so the difference is somewhere between 4 and 6 minutes.  Instead, just add similar logic as `dateadd()` above.